# Why choosing `unwrap_or_else` over `unwrap_or`?

Tags: performance, rust, unwrap

```rust
fn main() {
    let _one = None.unwrap_or("one".to_string());
    let _two = None.unwrap_or_else(|| "two".to_string());
}
```

Any particular reason why people should prefer `unwrap_or_else` over `unwrap_or`?

I have seen comments that `unwrap_or` is eager ([this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/55014) as an example). Does that mean the values in `unwrap_or` are always evaluated before program execution? And the `FnOnce` values in `unwrap_or_else` is called only when the program execute up to that line?

Comment: It’s a call, so the arguments are always evaluated. The documentation for `unwrap_or_else` also says as much.

Comment: Why do you use `||` instead of `|` for Boolean conditionals? They would both work, but `||` has a distinct advantage.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's the closure referred to as `FnOnce`, not a boolean? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else

Comment: @Jason Sorry if my comment's not clear. I wasn't implying that the `||` in the code above is a Boolean or. I was meaning to draw analogy between `|, ||` and the relationship between `unwrap_or` and `unwrap_or_else`. i.e. the latter of both pairs short-circuits.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thank you! That's very kind of you to explain. I am trying to grok the language as a beginner and your comment left me confused at first, not knowing you referred to bitwise `|` and logical `||`. If I understood you correctly, it's the same as short-circuiting with `&&` and `&`. I feel a bit silly now :-)

Comment: @Jason Exactly! Sounds like you've got it right.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Both are evaluated during the program's execution and can be arbitrary values. The difference is that:

- With `unwrap_or` the fallback value is evaluated just before `unwrap_or` is called, and therefore is evaluated whether it's needed or not (because Rust is an eager language).
- With `unwrap_or_else` the fallback value is evaluated only when `unwrap_or_else` triggers it (by invoking the function you pass), and therefore is evaluated only if it's needed.

Comment: let _two = None.unwrap_or_else(|| "two".to_string()); doesn't worked for me but let _two = None.unwrap_or_else(| _ | "two".to_string()); does any idea  why?

Comment: @HaseebSaeed just in case you haven't figured it out in 2 years (or for anyone like me stumbling on this): it's because the closure will be called with the error so it needs to accept a variable