# What's the equivalent of Scala's getOrElse in Rust?

Tags: rust, option-type

In Scala, I can use `getOrElse` as a convenient way to get a default value from `Option`, what's the equivalent of this in Rust?

```scala
val threeOpt = Some(3)
val shouldBeThree = threeOpt.getOrElse(-1) // got 3
```

Comment: Please note that the standard structs are documented: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html

Comment: Note to close voters: while the question shows no research effort, that is not grounds for closing. Downvote, instead, and move on, or merely ignore it. [Relevant Meta link.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

Comment: Good question! I think. @trentcl "while the question shows no research effort" — the linked rust-lang docs is a 500 - 1000 lines page, and then I think it makes sense to ask. Isn't one of the points with SO to avoid having to spend so much time reading "everything", and instead find answers quickly. Also, coming from a Scala background, "unwrap ..." is an unexpected name, and, personally, I was wondering if there's some "get ..." function I hadn't found. (I'm not OP, just another Scala & now Rust user.)

Comment: (B.t.w @trentcl agreed anyway that it's no grounds for closing, good point)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) or [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else)

- `unwrap_or` is eagerly evaluated
- `unwrap_or_else` is lazily evaluated

[See here for differences between eager and lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56726618/1080804)